# Error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras

I am getting the error:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Using the model:

```
X = np.reshape(x_train_tfidf.shape[0], 1, x_train_tfidf.shape[1])
print(X.shape)
model.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=True,
               input_shape=X))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(100,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Have a look at your dimensions before building your network..

Comment: @Aditya  x_train_tfidf (35000,1000), x_test (15000,1000)

Comment: @Aditya so? you know?

Comment: With `X = np.reshape(x_train_tfidf.shape[0], 1, x_train_tfidf.shape[1])` and `input_shape=X`, it looks like you are telling the LSTM layer that the input size is the input tensor itself, not its shape. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Answer (score 4):

It's probably this way..(not sure , give it a try)

**Iputs needs to be reshaped to be [samples, time steps, features]**

so

```
TrainX= np.reshape(TrainX,(TrainX.shape[0], 1, TrainX.shape[1]))
```

You need to passin the actual vector also?

Answer (score 1):

import numpy as np
np.expand_dims(X, axis = 0)

#This adds an additional dimension to your data without changing the value of your matrix.